# SQL Insert if Values doesn't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I need to insert values into a table, but if those values exist I want my script to not insert anything. I have pretty much gotten it solved, but I am stuck at the very end with my insert statement.

```
DECLARE @billableitemID int;
set @billableitemid = (select billableitemID from dbo.treatment where 
@billableitemid=treatment.id)
set @billableitemID = 256



CREATE TABLE #MembershipBenefitItem
    ( BenefitID int ,
      BillableItemTypeID int ,
      BillableItemID  int
    )

INSERT INTO #MembershipBenefitItem
    ( BenefitID ,
      BillableItemTypeID ,
      BillableItemID 
    )

 VALUES  (23450,1,@billableitemid),
(57256,1,@billableitemid)

select m.* from #MembershipBenefitItem  AS M
left join membershipbenefititem AS M1 on m.billableitemid= m1.billableitemid 
and m.billableitemtypeid= m1.billableitemtypeid 
and m.benefitid= m1.benefitID
and M1.billableitemID=@billableitemID and M1.billableitemtypeID=1 and 
M1.benefitID IN(23450,57256)  
where M1.ID is null

INSERT INTO MembershipBenefitItem
    ( BenefitID,
      BillableItemTypeID,
      BillableItemID 
    )

 select m.BenefitID, m.BillableItemTypeID, m.BillableItemID from 
#MembershipBenefitItem  AS M
left join membershipbenefititem AS M1 on m.billableitemid= m1.billableitemid 
 and m.billableitemtypeid= m1.billableitemtypeid 
 and m.benefitid= m1.benefitID
and M1.billableitemID=@billableitemID and M1.billableitemtypeID=1 and 
M1.benefitID IN(23450,57256) 
where M1.ID is null



DROP TABLE #MembershipBenefitItem
```

Comment: Another way to do such a thing would be the Merge statement. Just a thought. Typically though this is used for If exists Update else Insert

Comment: What are you stuck on?

Comment: `Where... And not exists (coorlated subquery on keys)`

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a good case to use `Merge` statement.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql

It would look something like:

```
MERGE MembershipBenefitItem AS trg
USING #MembershipBenefitItem AS src 
ON src.BillableItemID = trg.BillableItemID --and other join conditions
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
INSERT (col1, col2, col3) -- this will be inserted into trg table
VALUES (src.val1, src.val2, src.val3)
```